# WordPress po files

Tags: plugin-qtranslate, translation

Hi all I have one problem. Po file doesn't work. I use qtransltae-x for translation. And I create custom pot file

example

```
# Copyright (C) 2015 Gawatt
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Gawatt 1.0.0\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-06-03 11:30+0400\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2015-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.1\n"

#: club.php:25
msgid "zibil"
msgstr ""
```

after that I generate it`

```
# Copyright (C) 2015 Gawatt
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Gawatt 1.0.0\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-06-03 11:30+0400\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2015-06-03 12:45+0400\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.7.6\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);\n"
"Language: ru_RU\n"

#: club.php:25
msgid "zibil"
msgstr "sdfsdfsdfsdf"
```

code output `

```
<?php _e('zibil'); ?>
```

and in wp-config

```
define('WPLANG', 'ru_RU');
```

but when I switch language to russina it doesn't work, can you please help me thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `define('WPLANG', 'ru_RU');` in the `wp-config.php` is no longer needed, as WordPress stores this value in the database (starting from version 4.0).

However, I suppose your problem is actually something different.

### Your Steps:

#### Add a filter to `locale`

To ensure your language is set correctly, use a code like this:

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'f711_set_language' );
function f711_set_language( $locale ) {

    // you can use any switches to define the language here
    return 'ru_RU';

}
```

#### Use a textdomain

Change your Code to ensure your localized output is in a textdomain

```
<?php _e( 'zibil', 'your_textdomain' ); ?>
```

#### Be sure that you load the textdomain correctly

For Themes, you can use this. Be sure to define the right directory where your translation files are stored.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'f711_load_theme_textdomain');
function f711_load_theme_textdomain(){
    load_theme_textdomain( 'your_textdomain', get_template_directory().'/languages' );
}
```

For Plugins, use this:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'f711_load_plugin_textdomain' );
function f711_load_plugin_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'your_textdomain', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ); 
}
```

#### Be sure you named your `.po` correctly

The translation file HAS to be called `ru_RU.po` in your case.

You should be set up correctly afterwards.

Comment: Which step was the one that mattered? I suppose the loading of the textdomain?

Comment: I was editing a pre-built theme for a customer and since he bought an english one, I only had to set a filter for default locale and it worked.